# ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code works... sometimes.

This is for testing the capability of a service provided by my company

```
def insert_device(self):
    WDW(self.driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[data-target="#modalCreateDevice"]'))).click()

    # Variables

    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    name = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10))
    imei = random.randint(1000000000000, 9999999999999)
    functionality = ['3', '5']
    functionality = random.choice(functionality)
    printer = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
    printer = random.choice(printer)
    zone = '75'

    # Formulario

    nameField = WDW(self.driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@ng-repeat="(key, inputs) in formDevices"]/div[1]/input[@name="serial_mobile"]')))
    nameField.send_keys(name)
    imeiField = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@ng-repeat="(key, inputs) in formDevices"]/div[1]/input[@name="id_android_mobile"]')
    imeiField.send_keys(imei)
    functionalityField = Select(self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//combo-box[@title="Funcionalidad"]/div[1]/select[@name="id_app_type_device_mobile_fk"]'))
    functionalityField.select_by_value(functionality)
    printerField = Select(self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//combo-box[@title="Tipo de Impresora"]/div[1]/select[@name="id_app_tipo_impresoras_mobile_fk"]'))
    printerField.select_by_value(printer)
    zoneField = Select(self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//combo-box[@title="Zona"]/div[1]/select[@name="id_cms_zonas_mobile_fk"]'))
    zoneField.select_by_value(zone)
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[ng-click="_formSave()"]').click()
    btnRegister = WDW(self.driver, 10).until(ec.visibility_of((By.XPATH, '//div[@ng-show="showMessage"]/button[ng-click="acceptButton()"]')))
    btnRegister.click()
```

It should create a new device in the CMS and works, but only sometimes and i don't know why.

When it fails, throw:

```
Devices.py:38: in insert_device
    nameField.send_keys(name)
C:\Users\jacuc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:479: in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
C:\Users\jacuc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:633: in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
C:\Users\jacuc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:321: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try replacing this:

```
nameField = WDW(self.driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@ng-repeat="(key, inputs) in formDevices"]/div[1]/input[@name="serial_mobile"]')))
```

to this:

```
nameField = WDW(self.driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@ng-repeat="(key, inputs) in formDevices"]/div[1]/input[@name="serial_mobile"]')))
```

`element_to_be_clickable` ensures that the element is active and ready for interaction.

Comment: Short summary... presence means that it's in the DOM but it may not be visible or interactable. Visible means that it's displayed on the screen but in some cases like a disabled `INPUT` or `BUTTON`, it may not be clickable. Clickable means that it's visible and not disabled. It's probably fairly rare that you would want to wait for present unless you know the element is there but never going to be visible, etc.